# Why exe files can't run?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I think I overwrote my Windows 10 by Ubuntu. I still can see my installed software on Data C: and also on D:. But I can't open it. How can I solve it?

Comment: Most probably you did not overwote your Windows as long as you can see installed programs in C:\ ans D:\. Windows usually installs in C:\. If there are programs there, so should Windows be there too. If you want to boot into Windows again, presuming you can't do it now, you boot into Ubuntu, install a program called grub-customizer by using this command in a Terminal window: `sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`, start it up and add Win to the boot menu.

Comment: How does the question in the title relate to the question in the body? I don't see the connection between the two. Please clarify what you want to ask.

Comment: As for the question in the body, please run [Boot-Repair](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question "why exe files can't run":

The .exe files are Windows executables.  They are represented in a Windows-specific file format that the regular Linux operating system does not know how to load.  They depend on Windows-specific shared libraries (DLLs) that are not present on a Linux system.

How to solve your problem?

- Installing Wine on Linux may help, though it is not guaranteed to work for all applications.  (Wine depends on libraries that emulate the behavior of Windows, and that emulation is not 100% faithful to the original.)
- If you can see the Windows files on the C: and D: partitions, there is a good chance that you have only clobbered the Windows boot loader.  [This page](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/) talks about restoring the boot loader.